# How to pass objects of a class using Typescript/React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-props

I want a set up an Array of items, that have various properties, as a Prop on my component.

I'm trying to pass an array of items with different properties to a component, so, let's say that this is my array of objects:

```
`  let recepies = [
    {
      name: "A Name",
      imageURL: "V",
      difficulty: "C",
      time: 12,
      categories: "c",
    },
    {
      name: "aa",
      imageURL: "bb",
      difficulty: "cc",
      tieme: 13,
      categories: "c",
    }]
`
```

When I get to my Component, how do I define the Props?
I guessed

```
`interface Props {
    recepies: Object[];}
```

`should work, but when I get to:

```
    return(recepies.forEach(function (recipe) {

<RecepieCard
      name={recipe.namme}
```

I get that the property doesn't exist on the object. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you shod define and assign type to your object like this

```
type TRecepies = {
  name: string;
  imageURL: string;
  difficulty: string;
  time: number
  categories: string;
}

let recepies: TRecepies[] = [
{
  name: "A Name",
  imageURL: "V",
  difficulty: "C",
  time: 12,
  categories: "c",
},
{
  name: "aa",
  imageURL: "bb",
  difficulty: "cc",
  tieme: 13,
  categories: "c",
}]
```

and assign your object

```
interface IProps {
 recepies: TRecepies[];
}
```

then use them on your component and Be careful type correct property of your object

```
return(recepies.forEach(function (recipe) {
<RecepieCard
  name={recipe.name}
```

name no namme

Answer (score 0):

The `interface` is only the specififing the structure of the props.
You have to pass the Props to your component.

```js
type Recepy = {
  name: string,
  imageURL: string,
  difficulty: string,
  tieme: number,
  categories: string,
}

type Props = {
  recepies: Recepy[];
}

// as class component
class MyComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { recipes } = this.props;
    return recipes.map(recipe => (
      <RecipeCard
        key={i}
        name={recipe.name}
      />
    ));
  }
}

// or functional component
function MyComponent({recepies}: Props) {
  return recepies.map(
    (r, i) => (<RecepieCard
      key={i}
      name={recipe.namme}
    />)
  )
}
```

https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component